# How can I remove xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd in the return xml in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Produces("application/xml")]
public async Task<xml> mp([FromBody]xml XmlData)
{
    xml ReturnXmlData = null;
    ReturnXmlData = new xml()
    {
        ToUserName = XmlData.FromUserName,
        FromUserName = XmlData.ToUserName,
        CreateTime = XmlData.CreateTime,
        MsgType = "text",
        Content = "Hello world"
    };
    return ReturnXmlData;
}
[XmlRoot("xml")]
public class xml
{
    public string ToUserName { get; set; }
    public string FromUserName { get; set; }
    public string CreateTime { get; set; }
    public string MsgType { get; set; }
    public string MsgId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Now after I post these code to the local server which for test:

```
<xml>
  <ToUserName>123</ToUserName>
  <FromUserName>45</FromUserName>
  <CreateTime>12345678</CreateTime>
  <MsgType>text</MsgType>
  <Content>greating</Content>
</xml>
```

Then it will return these:

```
<xml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ToUserName>45</ToUserName>
  <FromUserName>123</FromUserName>
  <CreateTime>20190921203758</CreateTime>
  <MsgType>text</MsgType>
  <Content>Hello world</Content>
</xml>
```

Well, as you see. The XML data contains xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd which are not allowed in the remote server.

In addition, the remote server is not control by us that I can't change any code or any rules with it.

That means I have to modify the return XML like this:

```
<xml>
  <ToUserName>45</ToUserName>
  <FromUserName>123</FromUserName>
  <CreateTime>20190921203758</CreateTime>
  <MsgType>text</MsgType>
  <Content>Hello world</Content>
</xml>
```

How can I remove the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd when returns the XML? Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create custom serializer formatter for xml and you can inherit it from default `XmlSerializerOutputFormatter` implementation

```
public class XmlSerializerOutputFormatterNamespace : XmlSerializerOutputFormatter
{
    protected override void Serialize(XmlSerializer xmlSerializer, XmlWriter xmlWriter, object value)
    {
        //applying "empty" namespace will produce no namespaces
        var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        emptyNamespaces.Add("", "any-non-empty-string");
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value, emptyNamespaces);
    }
}
```

Add this formatter in `Startup`

```
services
    .AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatterNamespace());
    })
    //there should be one of the following lines in your application already in order to make xml serialization work
    //our custom output formatter will override default one since it's iterated earlier in OutputFormatters collection
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
    //.AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
```