# Remove ArrayOf From asp.net 【core】Web Api xml response

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core-webapi

I create default Asp.net core web API solution with Visualstudio 2019.

Change services.AddControllers(); to
services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();

Send Get Request to https://localhost:xxxxx/weatherforecast.
and I get following response

```
<ArrayOfWeatherForecast xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org.....>
  <WeatherForecast>
  ...
  </WeatherForecast>
......
</ArrayOfWeatherForecast>
```

But I really want to get response like

```
<WeatherForecasts>
  <WeatherForecast>
  ...
  </WeatherForecast>
......
</WeatherForecasts>
```

I found somes answers about remove arrayof frome asp.net.
Please help me. How to do this in asp.net core.

Comment: I think some sample code could help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the documentation on Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes

```
public class Group {
    [XmlArray("TeamMembers")]
    public Employee[] Employees;
}
```

The attribute gives the name in the serialization like this

```
<Group>
<TeamMembers>
    <Employee>
        <Name>Haley</Name>
    </Employee>
</TeamMembers>
</Group>
```

Comment: Hi,Athanasios Kataras,Thank you. Use your method I removed the arrayof. and removed namespaces in xml with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58040518/how-can-i-remove-xmlnsxsi-and-xmlnsxsd-in-the-return-xml-in-net-core). Now I got the format what I want. Thank you very match.